# In Django how can I search for related models based on the order they were added to a ManyToMany Field?

Tags: python, django

I have a model that has several manytomany relationships to it's self. The model has 1 parent, Many children, 1 greatgreat......grand parent . I want to keep the chain of parents stored on the model so I can simply search for objects that have a certain user associated with them to find to quickly find decendents on any level. What I want to know is how can I detrime what position they land on in the manytomany relationship.
so the model would look something like this(not actual code):

```
class Person:
user = onetoone(user)
greatgrandparent7generationsup = foreign(Person)
parents = many(user.user_name) //Geneology dad, grandad, greatgrandad .....
```

I have the code that would add the geneology in order, that's no problem.
I can figure out how to find all the decendents someone has.
What I want to be able to do is find out is once I have that decendant I want to know where in the liniege they lie(by determinging the if their the 1st 2nd 3rd .... model in the parents field). I'm trying to avoid a depth-first search. That's why I'm doing it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`django-mptt`](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/), it provides this feature out of the box.

Your model will be:

```
class Person(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

Now, you can do the following:

```
from yourapp.models import Person

dad = Person.objects.create(name="Dad")
john = Person.objects.create(name='John', parent=dad)
jim = Person.objects.create(name='Jim', parent=john)
```

To solve your lineage problem, once you have your tree in the database, each record (node) will have the following [methods](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html):

```
get_ancestors(ascending=False, include_self=False)
get_children()
get_descendants(include_self=False)
get_descendant_count()
get_next_sibling()
get_previous_sibling()
get_root()
get_siblings(include_self=False)
insert_at(target, position='first-child', save=False)
is_child_node()
is_leaf_node()
is_root_node()
move_to(target, position='first-child')
```

Comment: This looks promising, it may be very well be the solution to my particular needs as a whole. But I would still like to know the answer for my question of how to determine what order something was added on a manytomany. I pretty much have my whole project done though, and I would have to rewirte allot of it to use this. But Thanks though! +1 I'll accept this if nobody answers in the next day.

Comment: You can't do this, unless you create a custom manager and a custom field (which is already provided by `mptt`).

Comment: I figured out another approuch to doing what I wanted, but I'll probably use that mptt for my next version of this project(Which I'm working on another version of this project right now as well). (Like I said though, I've almost completed on this particular project, this was pretty much the last step.) You have been very helpful.